# R: data.frame to xts object: inadvertent conversion of numerical data to strings

Tags: r, type-conversion, xts

I am trying different ways to convert a data.frame to an xts time series. My current attempt gives me a result that I don't quite understand; I'd like to know why.

```
RX1 <- read.csv("RX1.csv")
RX1=setNames(RX1, c("Date", "PX_LAST"))
RX1 <- RX1[-1,] #just getting rid of first row as data not valid
RX1$Date <- as.Date(as.character(RX1$Date), format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

Now we should be good to go as we have the following data.frame

```
         Date PX_LAST
2 2006-07-26   89.57
3 2006-07-27   89.86
4 2006-07-28   90.15
5 2006-07-31   90.17
6 2006-08-01   90.06
7 2006-08-02   90.04

RX1.ts <- xts(RX1$PX_LAST, order.by = RX1$Date)
```

The result is

```
2006-07-26 "89.57"
2006-07-27 "89.86"
2006-07-28 "90.15"
2006-07-31 "90.17"
2006-08-01 "90.06"
2006-08-02 "90.04"
```

Can somebody help me understand what I did that caused the conversion of the price to characters ?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem using your code.  What is the class of `PX_LAST` in 'RX1'?  Based on the example, it should be numeric.  But, it can be different if the column have some non-numeric elements.

Comment: If I convert the PX_LAST to `factor`, it gives the same result as you showed.  (I am converting to `factor` as you didn't use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`.

Comment: Ok, if I understand correctly the problem is that the class of PX_LAST in 'RX1' is factor rather than num. I did't have this problem with a different .csv feed so I missed it. I would have to just change this before using the code I posted and that should sort it right ? Thanks both.

Comment: This solved the problem:                                                                `RX1$PX_LAST <- as.numeric(as.character(RX1$PX_LAST))`